# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception [wsdl] SOAP-ERROR

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, wamp

i'm trying to make a test with wsdl , soap and php , and i'm gettin the error :

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception [wsdl] SOAP-ERROR

I have for now 2 files , one is a given wsdl , and client.php just for test:

```
<?php

   $sClient = 'http://localhost/test/service/wbs.wsdl';
   $wsdl = new SoapClient ( '$sClient') ;
   echo "test";

?>
```

and i'm getin this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing
>   WSDL: Couldn't load from ' hp://localhost/test/service/wbs.wsdl' :
>   failed to load external entity " hp://localhost/test/service/wbs.wsdl"
>   in C:\wamp\www\Outbound\client.php:4 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\wamp\www\test\client.php(4): SoapClient->SoapClient('
>   hp://localh...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\test\client.php on
>   line 4

I did change the extension of soap in php.ini , i did all the modification posted in other posts , but nothing works .

Answer (score -1):

```
$wsdl = new SoapClient ( '$sClient') ;
```

This would not work. Use:

```
$wsdl = new SoapClient ( "$sClient") ;
```

Or - better:

```
$wsdl = new SoapClient ( $sClient) ;
```

Comment: Try `var_dump(file_get_contents("http://localhost/test/service/wbs.wsdl"));` and give output.

Comment: it shows : string ' the 4 first lines from wsdl and the echo test .

Comment: The error message `failed to load external entity` means that the loading is failed...

Answer (score -2):

Try it

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/test/service/wbs.wsdl");
```